# "I" of (I-VT) Like Bernie Sanders (I-VT)

Tags: word-meaning

Does "**I**" for, like Bernie Sanders (**I**-VT) in articles mean Sanders is an independent? I haven't thought Sanders is an independent. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: This isn't really a question about English and might be more appropriate on the Politics Stack Exchange.  But in any case, you're correct.  I-VT means *independent senator from Vermont*.  Sanders often caucuses with the Democrats, but does consider himself an independent.

Comment: It's not really an English question.  The question of "Is Sanders an independent" is certainly not a question of English.  The "(I, VT)" code is a journalistic shorthand, so probably on topic.

Comment: I guess it's debatable whether the question about the abbreviation is on topic, here.  I don't have any interest in having this debate, but what I was thinking was something like: a question about an industry-specific abbreviation (in this case, journalism) is often better suited to the site devoted to that topic.  For instance, ACK, ADSL, ARP, and ATM are all abbreviations of English words, but you'd probably do better to ask about them on Network Engineering.

Comment: @Juhasz That's your complete personal opinion. I don't know anything about ADK and which industry is having to do with.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't actually an English language question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "Independent, Vermont".  It is common in American political texts to add this code to senators' names to indicate their party and state.

Sanders is not a member of the Democrat, Republican or any other party, so he is an "independent".  However he does tend to align with the Democrats, and in the jargon of the Senate he is said to "caucus with the Democrats".  There are two independent Senators, Sanders and Angus King (I, ME) both of whom caucus with the Democrats.